# Spining a line $\frac{x-1}{0}=\frac{y}{3}=\frac{z}{2}$ aroung $z$ axis

Tags: 3d

This time I have an exercise of geometry.

I need to write an equation of surface which is obtained spining a line $$\frac{x-1}{0}=\frac{y}{3}=\frac{z}{2}$$ aroung $z$ axis.

Thank you!

Comment: I assume the $0$ in the denominator of $\frac{x-1}{0}$ is a typo?

Comment: @pjs36 not at all! The vector of direction is $(0, 3, 2)$

Comment: This makes no sense. Is it the equation of a line ? This basically describes a cone centered at the origin with radius $3$ at height $z=2$.

Comment: The expression $\frac{x-1}0$ is undefined, so most of your equation is meaningless. I can see what you’re getting at, but you need to be more careful and not simply plug values into a template. Because one of the components of the line’s direction vector is $0$, you can’t use this form of equation to describe it.

Comment: @Zubzub If I’m interpreting the OP’s nonsense equation correctly, the surface will be a hyperboloid of one sheet, not a cone: the line doesn’t pass through the origin.